# DB Procedure Test Aumation

Tags: java, automation, database-testing

I am from a JAVA background

I have a requirement for a automated Testing Process or Framework that can be used to verify our stored procedures and functions in Aurora DB compatible with Mysql. We have Cypress which we use to automate in UI side of APP.

But Currently we want to automate Testing process in DB.(i.e)

1. To create and maintain test cases for each procedures and functions
2. To run the complete or subset of test cases

I did a quick google search and could not find any frameworks or tools for it.

Suggestions on any already existing tools/ Design aspects for the same if it has to be developed is welcome.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Asking for tool and library recommendations is off-topic here; see [help/on-topic]. Your best bet is probably a web search. Years ago I briefly looked at pgtap, maybe there is something similar for other databases that works for you. Good luck!